# How to updgrade Hyperledgre farbic 2.0 chain-code from shim to contract api

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am working in hyperledger upgrading to new version `v2.0.1`, my query is my previous version `v1.4.3` of chain code contain shim interface in its implementation. How I can update existing chain to new version of chain code. Will old shim interface work with the new version of chain code and what is the difference between contract Api and shim interface? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabric v2 continues to support the contract api as well as the chaincode (shim) api, so you chaincode implementation should work without and changes in fabric v2. The contract api was introduced in fabric 1.4. The contract interface provides some extra capabilities and a more encapsulated programming model. 
About the best I can find showing the difference is here https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-node/release-2.0/api/index.html
which shows an example from each of the programming models but they aren't particularly good at showing the benefits of the contract api over the original shim api. Also I can't seem to find anywhere of a comparison between the 2 or definition of that capabilities the contract api provides. In a nutshell it

- removes some of the boilerplate code all chaincodes generally have to write (such as a function dispatcher and a serializer)
- provides the ability to bundle multiple contracts into a single chaincode package
- provides introspection information to clients if required
- can do input and output type checking via a defined metadata definition (which can be generated from source code if typescript is used)

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. When you are using AMB it is currently not possible to build your chaincode with the fabric-contract-api, only the fabric-shim interface

Comment: That's an issue with Amazon Managed Blockchain, suggest you raise in issue with them.